# openCV setup using Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, visual-studio-code, setup-project

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Code with MinGw for setting up openCV using C++. A simple "Hello World"  code executes successfully. But whenever I am trying to include an openCV library the compiler throws an error.

```
main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I searched for many solution on the internet but unfortunately none worked. Please help me in this regard as I am stuck with this issue for a long time.

[c_cpp_properties.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VuxQ.jpg)

[launch.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/576sl.jpg)

[task.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeOZN.jpg)

[main.cpp code I am trying to execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gpEJ.jpg)

Comment: So, obvious question, where have you installed OpenCV? Do you have a file called C:\openCV\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp on your system?

Comment: Look at the command that's executing when you build your program `g++ main.cpp -o main`. That's it. There's no mention of the opencv include path. so I guess something is wrong with your configuration.

Comment: Hii @john , thanks for a reply. Yes I have C:\openCV\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp on my system. And about "g++ main.cpp -o main" I don't have much idea about it. Can you help me out.. I referred: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/vs-code-with-opencv-c-on-windows-10-explained-256418442c52  article for the setup.

Comment: OK good. Sorry I'm not an expert in VS Code, but it's clear from your screen shots that the includePath you have setup in c_cpp_properties.json is being ignored. I'm sorry I have no idea why that might be.

Comment: @john it would very helpful if you refer this question to someone who might have some idea on this issue. Thanks for your help